# Simple JQuery syntax issue

Tags: jquery, variables, syntax

There is the part of my code which works perfectly

```
var image_mini = $('#map_mini');
var image_full = $('#map_full');

function state_change(data) { 
   // This is just part of code which show idea
   image_mini.mapster(data.state);
}

// This is full block of code, works correct
$("#map_full").mapster(
     $.extend({}, options, {
         onStateChange: state_change
     })
);
```

Now I need to enhance function state_change so, that it fill recive second agrument with image variable, which will be use insted of the directly writed image_mini.

Something like this (the code below is WRONG), but with CORRECT syntax code:

```
function state_change(data, working_image) {  
  working_image.mapster(...);
}

$("#map_full").mapster(
     $.extend({}, options, {
         onStateChange: state_change, image_mini
     })
);
```

I feel me lamer, but I haven't found example of correct sintax for passing two variables in such onStateChange... I tried some ideas, but it didn't work correctly.
Please help!

==============================
Added later:

Looks like my idea wasn't understood correctly, so I write more of code:

```
var image_mini = $('#map_mini');
var image_full = $('#map_full');

function state_change(data, working_image) {  
  working_image.mapster(data.state);
}

$("#map_full").mapster(
     $.extend({}, options, {
         onStateChange: state_change, image_mini
     })
);
$("#map_mini").mapster(
     $.extend({}, options, {
         onStateChange: state_change, image_full
     })
);
```

This is idea of what I want: both images must be crosslinked, so changes on one will be showed on both of them.

```
onStateChange: state_change, image_full
```

This is WRONG, I ask about correct syntax for the task.

Comment: What is `image_mini`  in the last line of your now working code? where  was it declared?

Comment: On first lines of the code I have showed:  var image_mini = $('#map_mini');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be as pretty, but you can do this using:

```
$.extend({}, options, {
    onStateChange : function (e) {
        state_change(e, image_mini);
    }
})
```

#### EDIT

To explain, your first version of code reads like this:

```
function state_change(data) {
    // ...
}
// ...
$.extend({}, options, {
    onStateChange : state_change
})
```

What happens here is that whenever `onStateChange` fires, it calls the `state_change` function. If this follows general jQuery parlance, then that function gets passed the jQuery event object as the function's first parameter. In this case, that event object would resolve as the `data` argument in your `state_change` function declaration.

My code above, follows the same logic:

```
onStateChange : function (e) {
}
```

So when `onStateChange` fires, it'll call that anonymous function, and pass in the event object as the first argument. This will resolve as `e` inside the handler function. Therefore:

```
onStateChange : function (e) {
    state_change(e, image_mini);
}
```

... performs mostly the same thing with respect to the event object. When the `onStateChange` event fires, the handler gets the event object as `e`, which it will then pass to the call to `state_change`. That'll resolve to `data` inside `state_change` as a result, and will not change how you use the original function much.

This way, however, we're free to pass in additional arguments into the call to `state_change`, like throwing in `image_mini` or whatever.

Comment: I am testing your variant now. What (e) means here?

Comment: @DaneSoul ~ Edited my answer to give an explanation of what's happening.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed unswer! This works and I have understood how it works and will be able to use the idea for solving other tasks as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are dropping image_mini in as a new item in the JSON object you are defining. That won't work. If you are looking to have it reference the map, you should be able to move that param into the first line of the state_change function

Because jQuery is going to do a basic function call of the question, you should have something like this:

```
    function state_change(data) {
    var image_mini = $("#mapMini");
    fullStateChange( data, image_mini );
}

function fullStateChange( data, image_mini ) {
    // Do stuffs here

    // This is just part of code which show idea
    image_mini.mapster(data.state);
}

// This is full block of code, works correct
$("#map_full").mapster(
      $.extend({}, options, {
            onStateChange: state_change
      })
);
```

Comment: That a bit more helpful? THe general idea is to have two functions, and have the initial one call the second one with more params. Or, just destroy the second function and have line 1 of the function call define image_mini

Comment: I have TWO images. And onStateChange must change parameters for one of them. So I need to pass to onStateChange WHICH of my images must be changed. Do you see why your code willn't solve my problem?

Comment: I mean that I will call the last part of my code twice: first for one image processing, then for another. Difficult to explain all the task, and it's not realy important to understand my current problem.